# Find OpenCyc concepts on the Web?

Tags: ontology, opencyc

Is it possible to look at OpenCyc ontology content on the Web?  I have been searching using Google and can find plenty of content *about* the Cyc ontology but no actual terms.

Comment: You could ask this on https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCyc semantic web pages are no longer available.  You might try running an OpenCyc yourself.

https://github.com/bovlb/opencyc

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of the OpenCyc RDF ontology is hosted by an Ai Blockchain endpoint (permanent web server), with Cool URIs as described by Tim Berners Lee.

Here is an example URI: https://api-ai-blockchain.com/kb-endpoint/opencyc/Baseball_Ball

The returned page shows English glosses of the term, and its more specific and more general terms as hyperlinks.

In addition to OpenCyc version 4, the Ai Blockchain endpoint contains ontology merged from WordNet 3.0 wordsenses and Wiktionary wordsenses.